# Cannot run a project because of Matlab API link problems

Tags: api, matlab, visual-c++

I have a C++ Visual Studio 2010 project, which I can run in x64 mode. But I want to run it in x32 also.. So here I have a problem - this project uses a Matlab API, which I never met before. I have these errors:

```
1>ReadMatrix.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _matOpen
1>ReadMatrix.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _matGetVariable
1>ReadMatrix.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mxGetDimensions_730
1>ReadMatrix.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mxGetPr
1>ReadMatrix.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mxDestroyArray
1>ReadMatrix.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _matClose
```

I looked in the Matlab folder(2011a) on the path
`..\MATLAB\R2011a\extern\include`, but found there only x64 files. What I should do?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to get hands on the 32bit libraries from a corresponding 32bit Matlab installation.

One possible simplification:
For compilation (not running) only, you do not necessarily need a full 32bit MATLAB installation, but only the library files (libmat, libmx, libmex).
This might simplify things if you'd e.g. like to compile the 32bit version for a colleague etc.

Comment: The MCR installer might even have these files.  There is a lot of extraneous stuff in the MCR installation folder that goes beyond just a runtime environment. It's worth a look.